# jQuery is clicking two elements at the same time and not waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making Chrome browser extension with jQuery and I want to click on one element on the website and wait for for ~10 seconds and click another element but when I tested this the program first waited for ~10 seconds and then it clicked on both of the elements.

```
    console.log("pred adrenalinom", new Date());
    $('#first')[0].click();
    console.log("za adrenalinom", new Date());

    const sleepTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 + 10000);

    setTimeout(async () => {
        console.log("pred drinkom", new Date());

        $("#second")[0].click();

        console.log("za drinkom", new Date());
    }, sleepTime);
```

This is what I get in the console. It looks like the click is executed but not processed until the other click.

[image: console.log]

Comment: have you tried removing the async from the setTimeout? or you mean that $('#first')[0].click(); and  $("#second")[0].click(); fires at the same time after 10 seconds ?

Comment: @VirojFernando I will try removing async. Yes they both fire at the same time after 10 seconds but it should be first click and then wait for 10 seconds and the second click

Comment: bit strange. try and give an update.

Comment: @VirojFernando removing async didn't help - clicks still fire at the same time. I managed to fix it by using nested timeouts which is not ideal.